# "ImportError: No module named freezegraph" Does the freezegraph should be created by myself? or is it avilable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When I run tensor.py it tell me that  "ImportError: No module named freezegraph"
Does it means I should create "freezgraph" by myself? sorry,I'm confused,looking forward for your introduction~
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import pmt
import freezegraph

def save_graph(sess,output_path,checkpoint,checkpoint_state_name,input_graph_name,output_graph_name,outname):
 　　
    checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(output_path,checkpoint)
    # defaults to saving all variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=0,latest_filename=checkpoint_state_name)
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(),output_path,
                           input_graph_name)

    # We save out the graph to disk, and then call the const conversion
    # routine.
    input_graph_path = os.path.join(output_path, input_graph_name)
    input_saver_def_path = ""
    input_binary = False
    input_checkpoint_path = checkpoint_prefix + "-0"
    output_node_names = outname
    restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
    filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
    output_graph_path = os.path.join(output_path, output_graph_name)
    clear_devices = False

    freezegraph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver_def_path,
                              input_binary, input_checkpoint_path,
                              output_node_names, restore_op_name,
                              filename_tensor_name, output_graph_path,clear_devices, "")


def load_graph(output_graph_path,inp,out,ckpt_path=""):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        output_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with tf.Session() as sess:

            with open(output_graph_path, "rb") as f:

                output_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
                _ = tf.import_graph_def(output_graph_def, name="")

                n_input = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(inp)
                output = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(out)
                return (sess,n_input,output)
```

Comment: Are you referring to this script? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py 

If so, you probably want to do `import freeze_graph` (with an underscore) but there may be other problems with the Python path.

Comment: I get the code from:https://github.com/chrisruk/cnn  I know there is a "freeze_graph.py"in TF,I'm confused of the use of import"freezegraph.py"directly

Comment: I change the "import freezegraph " to "from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph" then I get new errors:

Answer (score 0):

I change the "import freezegraph " to "from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph" then I get new errors:

```
File "/home/imatrix/chrisruk/cnn-master/train_cnn.py", line 46, in <module>
    save_graph(sess,"/tmp/","saved_checkpoint","checkpoint_state","input_graph.pb","output_graph.pb","out/Softmax")
  File "/home/imatrix/ chrisruk/cnn-master/tensor.py", line 35, in save_graph
    filename_tensor_name, output_graph_path,clear_devices, "")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 103, in freeze_graph
    _ = importer.import_graph_def(input_graph_def, name="")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 308, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-pack`enter code here`ages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2339, in create_op
    self._add_op(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2033, in _add_op
    "is already used" % op.name)
ValueError: cannot add op with name Crossentropy/Mean/moving_avg as that name is already used
```